# Load Test and Stress Test in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We need to perform the load test and stress test in SharePoint Server 2010. 
How can we perform the tests and is there any automated tool to handle it effectively?

Answer (score 4):

Today I've been looking at this very thing myself.  Here are some of the more useful links I've found.

I haven't tried this but it sounds interesting [New SharePoint 2010 Load Test Toolkit Released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2010/08/07/new-sharepoint-2010-load-test-toolkit-released.aspx).

As well Microsoft provides some guidance in [Performance testing for SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758659.aspx)

This article also contains lots of useful information and links [SharePoint (Performance, Stress ) Load Testing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanjaynarang/archive/2009/04/18/sharepoint-performance-stress-load-testing.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I used Load Runner to do load testing in 2007. Admittedly I haven't had to do it in 2010 yet, but I had a pretty good experience with Load Runner.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, the load testing suite is pretty amazing.